# Thread waiting on two threads to notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I'll explain with an example. I have a construction site with a building needed to be done. Let's say a building requires bricks and cement for it to keep building. (a thread object with two private variables on current state of materials). The building has a truck and a van that supply it with needed materials (truck for cement and van for bricks, two separate thread objects). Each second the building spends 100kg of cement and 50kg of bricks. If any of the two is less than that at any moment the construction stops until the truck and van supply it with enough materials.

I'm not sure how to go about this, as there are 2 conditions needed to be met (sufficientBricks and sufficientCement). In an attempt to solve, does the following part of code make any sense?

```
Building extends Thread
//...
public void run() {
    super.run();

    lock.lock();

    while (true) {
        if (cement < 100 || bricks < 50)
            try {
                insufficientBricksawait(); //Can you do something like this?
                insufficientCementawait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        spent += 150;
        bricks -= 50;
        cement -= 100;

        try {
            sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How would I signal to Building to continue work when it it has to wait on two threads to notify it that the condition is satisfied?

Comment: You can model the delivery of bricks and cement by separate [blocking queues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Since you need both materials, you can use `take()` to block until you have a delivery of one; then use `take()` on the other to block until you have a delivery of the other.

Comment: Please add the missing code for an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: That generally looks okay, although a few minor tweaks: make sure your vars are volatile, and if the thread is interrupted, it will currently continue as if there is sufficient bricks and cement.

Comment: I'm sorry i couldn't give any more than this, I thought it wouldn't be precise. Trying to find an idea on how to implement a thread that has to wait on 2 conditions from 2 separate threads, if such a thing is possible

Comment: " 2 conditions" => Sounds like a job for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html ?

Comment: Yes, but doesn't a thread wait for a  *single* object to notify? Basically what I;m trying to achieve for the bulding thread is: "okay, I waited for cement, I got it, but I still have to wait for bricks to continue".

Comment: Read Andy Turner's comment again:  If you need bricks _and_ mortar, then you can wait for them sequentially:  First wait for the bricks, then wait for the mortar.  Or, do it in the opposite order.  Doesn't matter because you need both.  It's more complicated if your thread must wait for one thing _or_ the other.

Comment: @AndyTurner please turn your comment into an answer!